# PYTHON - PYMONGO - Invalid Syntax with $or

Tags: python, python-2.7, mongodb-query, pymongo

I can't seem to get this to work with pymongo it was working before I added the $or option. Am I missing something obvious with this

`dataout = releasescollection.find( { $or: [{"l_title":{"$regex": "i walk the line", "$options": "-i"}}, {"artistJoins.0.artist_name":{"$regex": "Johnny Cash", "$options": "-i"}}]}).sort('id', pymongo.ASCENDING).limit(25)`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "discogs.py", line 51
    dataout = releasescollection.find( { $or: [{"l_title":{"$regex": "i walk the line", "$options": "-i"}}, {"artistJoins.0.artist_name":{"$regex": "Johnny Cash", "$options": "-i"}}]})
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Running the below directly in mongo works but I'm missing something in the switchover to python

`db.releases.find( { $or: [{"l_title":{"$regex": "i walk the line", "$options": "-i"}}, {"artistJoins.0.artist_name":{"$regex": "Johnny Cash", "$options": "-i"}}]}).sort({'id':1}).limit(25)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should've relized this far sooner, once I added the $or it needs to be in quotes. So this works:

`dataout = releasescollection.find( { "$or": [{"l_title":{"$regex": "i walk the line", "$options": "-i"}}, {"artistJoins.0.artist_name":{"$regex": "Johnny Cash", "$options": "-i"}}]}).sort('id', pymongo.ASCENDING).limit(25)`

Comment: You found the solution but, for those who will explore this in the future, quotes must enclose the `$or`expression as indicated in the [documents](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update).